# Perl regex to "Count number of whitespace" inside parens: () or double quotes ""

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I want to count the number of white space present inside: () OR "". 
Can that be done using a perl regex.

Example:

Let the string be:

```
abcd(efg h i)jkl        -> count = 2
abc def(dfdsff fd)dfdsf -> count = 1
```

Comment: Yes it can. If you capture the pattern you want to match against, you can then count the number of things it captured.

Comment: Can you have nested groups? E.g. `abcd(efg (abc ) hi)` or even `abcd(efg "abc " hi)`?

Comment: and what about "abc(d e)fg(h i)"?

Comment: FYI, it would probably be cleaner code, and possibly more efficient to just traverse the string and count the spaces using in indexed loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
( )(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|( )(?=[^(]*\))
```

You can try this.Count the number of groups.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/zM7yV5/6

Here we find `space` which is inside `""` or `()`.Once we find that we capture and count the number of groups we found and that is the answer.

`( )(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` ==>here lookahead ensures it finds a `"` ahead of it followed by groups of `""` ahead of it.In short odd numbers of `"` ahead of it.That enables us to pick `space` which is between `""` as it will have odd number of `"` ahead of it.

`( )(?=[^(]*\))` ==> hre lookahead implies that it should find a `)` ahead of it without `(` .So this enables us to cpature space between `()`.Though this will not work for nested `()`.

Comment: That is one horrible looking regex, without explanation or context. No offense, but perhaps you should add those things. No downvote from me, but others might.

Comment: and the complexity will explode with long strings.

Comment: When I asked for an explanation, I did not mean that you should repeat the original question once more, but that you should explain what your regex does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to find and capture the bracketed string, and `tr///` to count the number of whitespace characters in the catptured string.

This program demonstrates the principle. It reads the strings from the `DATA` file handle (I have used the sample data from your question, but duplicated it to provide samples that contain double quotes) and assumes that there is *only one* pair of parentheses or quotation marks in each string.

I have used the *branch reset* construct `(?| ... )` so that the bracketed contents are captured in `$1` regardless of whether it was the parentheses or the double quotes that matched.

It is a simple matter to modify the code if the assumptions are untrue, but you have been asked about it in comments and haven't provided an answer.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'max';

my $re = qr/ (?|
    \( ( [^()]+ ) \)
  |
    " ( [^()]+ ) "
) /x;

my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;

my $width = max map length, @data;

for (@data) {

  chomp;

  if ( $_ =~ $re ) {
    my $count = $1 =~ tr/\x20\t//;
    printf "%-*s -> count = %d\n", $width, $_, $count;
  }
}

__DATA__
abcd(efg h i)jkl
abc def(dfdsff fd)dfdsf
abcd"efg h i"jkl
abc def"dfdsff fd"dfdsf
```

**output**

```
abcd(efg h i)jkl        -> count = 2
abc def(dfdsff fd)dfdsf -> count = 1
abcd"efg h i"jkl        -> count = 2
abc def"dfdsff fd"dfdsf -> count = 1
```